# Unable to get ViewModel instance in RecyclerView.Adapter class Kotlin

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Kotlin and trying to create an alarm clock app. In this app I'm using LiveData and RecycleView. Right now I need to change the alarm status:

[image: switcher]

Here is my **AlarmsRecyclerAdapter** where i tried to create `.onClickListener{}`

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AlarmsRecyclerAdapter.AlarmItemHolder, position: Int) {
        //mAlarmViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( context as Fragment)[AlarmViewModel::class.java]
        if (mAlarms != null) {
            val current = mAlarms!!.get(position)
            holder.view.edit_time_button.text = current.printTime()
            holder.view.switch_alarm_enabled.isEnabled = current.enabled

            holder.view.switch_alarm_enabled.setOnClickListener {
                current.enabled = !current.enabled
               // mAlarmViewModel.insert(current)
            }
        } else {
            // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
            holder.view.edit_time_button.text = "no timer"
        }
    }
```

I also tried to get instance of `ViewModel` in the comment line, but it just throws errors like

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
>           at com.xxx.alarm.AlarmsRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlarmsRecyclerAdapter.kt:58)
>           at com.xxx.alarm.AlarmsRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AlarmsRecyclerAdapter.kt:33)

I need to change the alarms in the database, so how can I get an instance of `ViewModel` in the adapter class? Or is there better way to manage the data changing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure about getting your ViewModel inside your RecyclerView, and not really sure if this would be considered best practice. But here is the way I am doing this, and have others seen doing it.
First you create your ViewModel in you Fragment.
Then you observe your AlarmData and when it changes you update the data in your RecyclerAdapter.

So in your Fragment you do something like this():

```
mAlarmViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of( context as Fragment)[AlarmViewModel::class.java]
mAlarmViewMode.getAlarms().observe(...
    mAdapter.setData(newData)
```

and inside you Adapter you add the following:

```
setData(data:List) {
    mAlarms= data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

this should keep your data updated.

Now for the changing of your data.
Try Setting the OnclickListener inside your ViewHolder, as this is going to increase the speed of your app.
to get your current value you could do this:

```
val current = mAlarms!!.get(getAdapterPosition())
```

Finally you shold add a Interface to your Adapter, something like this:

```
interface ItemSelectedListener {
  fun onItemSelected(item:Any, v:View)
}
```

Set this interface from your Fragment and call it from the onClickListener.
Then you have all the data you need inside your Fragment and can modify it from there

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually i need change my alarms in database, so thats why i need that `ViewModel` instance. If I change them in DB it should changes in frontend because of `LiveData`.

Comment: So I am guessing you are using Room and LifeData too? When you are changing something in your database, the Observer from you LifeDataObject will trigger, and update you recyclerview.

Comment: Ye, you're right. But i cant get instance of `ViewModel` to use database like this `mAlarmViewModel.insert(current)`. In `Fragment` class i can get instance in this way `mAlarmViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[AlarmViewModel::class.java]` but I need to pass some parameter to method `.of()` to get instance in **AlarmsRecyclerAdapter** class.

Comment: Like I said, you could just move the data modification to your Fragment, there you would have everything you need. If you really need to get the ViewModel inside your Recyclerview, just pass your Fragment as additional Argument in the constructor and use this reference, to get you ViewModel.

Comment: thanks a lot! Could you please explain me in which way i can move data modification to Fragment? I need my data be modified when switcher clicked and i can handle it only in **AlarmsRecyclerAdapter** class. Am I wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this Gist: https://gist.github.com/glm9637/db7c702074514718b34796e462be44a1 I am not proficient in Kotlin, but i hope it helps.

Comment: What is **newData**??

Comment: newData is the data loaded from your observer, so the updated Data you want to display